# Was the phrase "hello" popularized because of the name of Alexander Graham Bell's wife/girlfriend "Margaret Hello"?

Tags: history, language, etymology

This is a popular explanation of the etymology of the word hello, seen in many email forwards:

> When you lift the phone, you say "Hello".
>
> Do you know what is the real meaning of "Hello" It is the name of a
>   girl.
>
> Yes .... and do you know who is that girl
>
> Margaret Hello. She was the girlfriend of Graham bell who invented the
>   telephone. One can forget the name of Graham bell but not his
>   girlfriend - that is Love !!!! or whatever....
>
> Now you know ... well it is much better that pick up the phone and say
>   "Margaret".

Was Bell involved with a woman named Margaret Hello and is that the reason the word "hello" was popularized?

Comment: A quick look at [Alexander Graham Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Graham_Bell#Family_life) would reveal that he was engaged to Mabel Hubbard at the time.

Comment: @Mark And who is to say Bell didn't have a bit on the side? ;-)

Comment: Also, Bell wanted people to use "Ahoy" instead. It was Edison that wanted people to use Hello.  http://www.npr.org/sections/krulwich/2011/02/17/133785829/a-shockingly-short-history-of-hello  The downvotes are probably because "someone told me". That is a pretty non-notable claim, and closing it as such.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella How is it a non-notable claim? Snopes has a article on it. It is usually circulated using facebook and e-mail forwards.

Comment: @Alaukik now that the question received an edit, I see it has been reopened. Keep in mind, just stating "someone told me" or "I saw on facebook" isn't quite enough for this site, and why it was initially closed and downvoted. Closing allows you a chance to bring the question in line with the standards of the site while not continuing to get the negative reputation. There was no intent of punishment or chastising.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**No**.

Thomas Edison is in fact credited with the first use of the word [Hello on the telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello#Telephone), and the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello#Etymology) of the word is well documented.

Furthermore, Graham Bell was engaged to [Mabel Gardiner Hubbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mabel_Gardiner_Hubbard) at the time of the first phone call (and in fact had been courting her for some time), who he eventually went on to marry.

There is, in fact, a [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/language/eponyms/hello.asp) article on this hoax.

Comment: Did Bell also want to use "ahoy!" instead of "hello" anyway? Or is that a myth too?

Comment: Actually, that is a little off. The general consensus appears to be he suggested "ahoy-hoy".

Comment: Ahh.. Still eons away from "hello" however.

Comment: But there does appear some inconsistencies in the specifics, everyone agrees that he either used "ahoy", or "ahoy. ahoy", or possibly "ahoy-hoy"

Comment: Let alone that Bell is considered the inventor of the telephone only in the US, whereas there's historical evidence that [this is not the case](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13401/13401-h/13401-h.htm#13)

Comment: @Sklivvz Unless it can be shown that Bell's invention was derived from Meucci's, then Bell's still counts as an independent invention. In popular history, we frequently credit the inventor who *popularized* an invention rather than the one with the earliest independent invention.

Comment: @called2voyage meucci did popularize the invention as well. the *patent* was assigned to bell, but was contested by meucci

Comment: @Sklivvz To the best of my understanding, Meucci's electromagnetic telephone was *not* widely recognized until later, regardless of its efficacy, which to me means it was not popularized first.

Comment: @Sklivvz On the other hand, [it does appear](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2002/jun/17/humanities.internationaleducationnews) that Bell may have "borrowed" Meucci's ideas. So the claim may have weight after all.